# Irreducible and regular representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I was working on representations of $S_3$ and thought about the following problems:

The symmetric group $S_4$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ by permuting coordinates. Decompose this representation into irreducible representation..

For $S_3$ the permuting matrix was $6 \times6$, so for $S_4$ it would even be bigger. However, how can we decompose it into irreducibles? Due to conjugacy classes in $S_4$ there are 5 irreducible representations.

Comment: I have no idea what the first sentence of your first paragraph is about. But, for any group acting 2-transitively on a set $X$, the corresponding (complex) permutation representation of degree $|X|$ decomposes as a sum of the trivial representation (acting on vectors $(\lambda,\ldots,\lambda)$ and an irreducible representation of degree $|X|-1$ acting on vectors with sum of entries equal to $0$.

Comment: @James: there are many ways to decompose representations into the irreducibles. It's hard to help you without knowing what you know and what you're supposed to use. E.g., are you required to use pure linear algebra to block-diagonalize the matrices? Or can you use standard character theory or other tools from rep. theory?

Comment: @Marek: Yes, we can use tools from representation theory. In fact, I am looking at Algebra by Artin and I think all the material that Artin covers in chapter 10 is very much known and can be used. I apologize for being not clear on my question

Comment: Could you perhaps reread your own question, and make it resemble more closely English prose? Just so one (we) doesn't have to read most sentences twice.

Comment: @JamesBond:  You may be confusing *permutation representation*, in which group elements act by permuting indices and is $3$ dimensional for $S_3$, with *regular representation*, in which group elements act by translation on the group itself and is $3! = 6$ dimensional.